# Prevent default single click event on double click on a link in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

My code is pretty simple:

```
var clickCount = 0, clickEl = [];
var manualClick = false;
$(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    if (e.altKey || e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey) {
        return;
    }
    clickCount = clickCount + 1;
    clickEl[clickCount] = this;

    var that = this;
    if (1 === clickCount) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (2 === clickCount && clickEl[1] === clickEl[2]) {
                window.stop();
                embed_anchor(that);
            }
            clickCount = 0;
        }, 250);
    }
});
```

It basically checks if there is double click. If yes, it cancel the single click redirect using `window.stop()`. It used to work great, but I don't know if it's Chrome or my new PC, `window.stop()` failing 9.5/10 times.

Even a simple code like:

```
setInterval(function () {
    window.stop();
}, 1);
```

is not able to prevent redirect these days. Is there any alternative solution for me. I ideally don't want to use `e.preventDefault()` because this script is part of TamperMonkey and I feel `e.preventDefault()` will break single click on ton of sites.

Is there any way to hold the event for 250 ms, or cancel and raise the same event (It must behave like last one so no issues with any site). I am open too pretty much everything. I would prefer if my script don't work on some sites rather than breaking any site.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: where is it failling? how do you know it fails 9.5 times out of 10? maybe you are not clicking under that 250 ms window

Comment: @miguelglz If I set window.stop() on 1ms loop on a random page in console, it still fails 9.5/10 times

Comment: does it works with 1000 ms?

Comment: `window.stop()` is not the way to do this. That is the same as clicking the stop button in your browser. It is unreliable because the new page is occasionally loading very quickly before your 250ms timeout.

Comment: Why not use a check within a single click event (like is ctrl+shift being held) and preventDefault only in that case?

Comment: @Herohtar Yeah! It have become very unreliable now even for personal use. Earlier things used to load slow and now processors are much faster. It is just for a personal project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the piece of code I wrote to solve my problem:

```
$.fn.on2 = function(type, sel, handler) {
    this[0].addEventListener(type, function(event) {
        var t = event.target;
        while (t && t !== this) {
            if (t.matches(sel)) {
                handler.call(t, $.event.fix(event));
            }
            t = t.parentNode;
        }
    }, true);
}

var clickEvents = [];
$(document).on2('click', 'a', function (event) {
    if (event.altKey || event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey || this.text.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    clickEvents.push(event);

    if (event.originalEvent.isTrusted) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }

    var target = this;
    if (1 === clickEvents.length) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (2 === clickEvents.length && clickEvents[0].target == clickEvents[1].target) {
                doWhatever(clickEvents[0].target);
            } else {
                clickEvents[clickEvents.length-1].target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", clickEvents[clickEvents.length-1].originalEvent));
            }
            clickEvents = [];
        }, 250);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `dblclick` javascript event. It's usable on all updated browsers currently.

There's already a post here: [Detect if browser/device supports double click events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353763/detect-if-browser-device-supports-double-click-events) to detect if it's supported by using a timeout to check if there is an another click after the first click.

Comment: But I cannot prevent single click redirect there

Comment: Check the answer I linked (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14353886/7355534), just add a `preventDefault()` on the first click condition before the `setTimeout `, and add your event function if there's only one click, or two, in the conditions inside the `setTimeout `

Comment: I don't want to use `preventDefault` as I mentioned

Comment: The only alternatives to `preventDefault()` method are `stopPropogation()` and `return false`. Check this to see more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971284/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false-no-jquery

Comment: But they are same thing. I don't want to cancel event in first place :)

Comment: Oww... And I suppose it has to be targeted on a link ?

Comment: It can be any anchor tag on the internet.

Comment: But this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14353886/7355534) still doesn’t work if you set the first event and the second event without any preventDefault ?